# Creating Confluence pages in Attlassian Confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

I am creating a confluence page in Atlassian Confluence. But I need to have a provision for creating links in this page which when clicked will redirect to another page.

For eg: I have a main page **Cars**.
This page will list all the Car names like Honda, Toyota, etc. On clicking each one, it will redirect to another page which shows the information related to that car such as the Seating capacity, Tank capacity, etc.

Now I need to have a button **Add car** in the main page **Cars** which when clicked will prompt for entering certain info like Car name, capacity, etc.
On submitting this it will automatically create a page and the corresponding link for that will be available in the main page **Cars**.

I tried many ways in confluence using the macros. But I am missing something. 
Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a page template for that.
The template editor is kinda like the normal page editor, but allows you to use variables, which can be prefilled on page creation.

Then you add the "create from template" macro to your base page, and tell it where to create the page from your template.